# Pokemon Uranium and Winetricks Problem

Tags: games, wine

I am using a Macbook Pro Version 10.10.2, and I have OSX Yosemite. I've been trying for hours to get Wine, and I downloaded the 1.6.1 version of Wine. Then, on the Windows file, Pokemon Uranium Beta 4.0.msi, I right clicked the file and opened it with Wine. Then I followed the instructions [How to run Uranium on Mac OS X](http://pokemon-uranium.tumblr.com/post/106346927830/how-to-run-uranium-on-mac-os-x)

And I did everything except for the 6th instruction, because I couldn't find d3dx9_36, directplay, and directmusic on Winetricks. So with just until the fifth instruction, I launched the game.

And it worked just fine, but at the part where there is a problem in the power room, and the Mum says "What's happening...?", the game starts freezing for a few seconds and then it says,

> Program Uranium.exe has encountered a serious problem and needs to close. Sorry for the inconvenience.

I clicked for the details so I can mention the details in the post, but Wine just quits and I can't view the details. Is there any way I could fix this? Or, is there a problem with Wine that I can't find d3dx9_36, directplay, and directmusic on Winetricks?

Answer (score 1):

You have to go into the winetricks menu from the dropdown menu on the taskbar, and it should all be there.  If its not there, you should try deleting your copy of wine and reinstalling the latest version.